# How to avoid Wrong recognition and Convention of Date - from String to Date format in Pandas Columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas column with dates as strings
"12-10-2021  00:00" and "13-10-2021  00:00"
i am using
`df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')`
output is coming as dates
2021-12-10 and 2021-10-13 where months and days are not converted correctly.
[image]

How do i get the dates correctly as

2021-10-12

2021-10-13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```